# New environment variables missing

Tags: c, linux

I set a new environment variable in my program, but i cannot found it from shell:

```
int main()
{
    if(!setenv("TEST","22222",0)) perror("");
    sleep(1000);
    return 0;
}
```

I try it with

```
$ a.out &
[3] 605
$ Success

$ cat /proc/605/environ|grep 2222
$ ps e 605|grep 2222
$
```

Any ideas?
Many thanks.

Comment: FWIW, this is how you can do it ;-) `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp){ strcpy(envp[0], "TEST=22222"); sleep(1000); }`. This will overwrite other environment variable(s), but it's the only way you can do it, since `/proc/<pid>/environ` does no magic, it just reflects the contents of an area of the process's virtual memory, whose start and length do not change while the process is running.

Comment: And BTW, take care with the 3rd argument of `setenv`; it means "overwrite"; if it's 0 and the `TEST` variable is already present in the environment, its value will be left unchanged and `setenv` will return a 0 (*success*) status.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in `man 5 proc` (pay attention to the bolded paragraph):

> `/proc/[pid]/environ`
>
> This file contains the initial environment that was set
> when the currently executing program was started via
> `execve`(2).  The entries are separated by null bytes
> (`'\0'`), and there may be a null byte at the end.  Thus,
> to print out the environment of process 1, you would do:
>
> ```sh
> $ cat /proc/1/environ | tr '\000' '\n'
> ```
>
> **If, after an `execve`(2), the process modifies its
> environment (e.g., by calling functions such as
> `putenv`(3) or modifying the `environ`(7) variable
> directly), this file will not reflect those changes.**

Answer (score 0):

The variable is set. You can confirm it via:

```
printf ("%s \n",getenv("TEST"));
```

which returns `22222` as expected.